# Chart.js Faceting

Tags: javascript, chart.js, data-visualization, axis

Are there any plugins or config options inside chart.js to create faceted charts?

I have a requirement to create faceted charts using chart.js.
A faced chart shares the X and/or Y axis across multiple charts. (see attached image for an example) and is a very common solution to many design visualization problems, but is absent from chart.js

**Update**
Chart.js V3 added [Stacked Axis](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/3.7.0/samples/scales/stacked.html) which could potentially be used for creating faceted charts in chart.js

example of faceted charts
[image]

Comment: Are you trying to basically have all of these colored lines on one graph?

Comment: @DennisKozevnikoff not quite. I'm trying to create faceted charts, i.e. so the charts share the same y-axis. Similar to the image in the question.

Comment: I'm still confused by what you are trying to do. Those charts in your image are separate, each one has it's own y-axis and x-axis. Can you maybe produce an image of exactly what you need done?

Comment: @DennisKozevnikoff in the image the charts all share y and x-axis with at least one other chart. For example, the AAPL chart has y values between 0 and 200 but uses the 0-800 scale so the values can be compared. This is called 'facet'. this is an example of creating a similar effect with another charting library and a deeper description https://api.taucharts.com/basic/facet.html I'm trying to create a facet of line charts in chart.js

Comment: Sounds to be a table of charts, where all axes should have the save min, max, and count options. The Y axes should be visible only on chart instances on the first column, the X axes should be visible only on last row. If correct, it's doable with Chart.js as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I have understood well your use case, you need a matrix of chart instances with the "same" axes.
In the below snippet, I used `min`, `max` and `ticks.count` (I think they should be enough) to be sure that the axes have the same dimensions.

```js
const getCanvas = function(id) {
  return document.getElementById(id).getContext("2d");
};
const createConfig = function(title, data, x, y) {
  return {
    type: 'line',
    data: {
        labels: ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'],
        datasets: [
            {
                data,
                borderColor: 'green',
                borderWidth: 2,
            }]
    },
    options: {
      scales: {
        x: {
          ticks: {
            display: x
          }
        },
        y: {
          min: 0,
          max: 100,
          ticks: {
            display: y,
            count: 5
          }
        }
      },
        plugins: {
          legend: false,
          tooltip: false,
          title: {
            display: true,
            text: title
          }
        }
    }
  };
}
new Chart(getCanvas('myChart1'), createConfig('Amazon', [10, 20, 30, 5, 55], false, true));
new Chart(getCanvas('myChart2'), createConfig('Google', [10, 20, 30, 5, 55], false, false));
new Chart(getCanvas('myChart3'), createConfig('IBM', [10, 20, 30, 5, 55], true, true));
new Chart(getCanvas('myChart4'), createConfig('Microsoft', [10, 20, 30, 5, 55], true, false));
```

```css
.myChartDiv {
  max-width: 300px;
  max-height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js@3.9.1/dist/chart.min.js"></script>
<html>
  <body>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td>
    <div class="myChartDiv">
      <canvas id="myChart1" width="300" height="200"/>
    </div>
        </td>
        <td>
    <div class="myChartDiv">
      <canvas id="myChart2" width="300" height="200"/>
    </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
    <div class="myChartDiv">
      <canvas id="myChart3" width="300" height="200"/>
    </div>
        </td>
        <td>
    <div class="myChartDiv">
      <canvas id="myChart4" width="300" height="200"/>
    </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>  
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: thanks. This is what I'm going to use. Just need some calculations to get the max value. I have noticed chartjs added something called stacked axis with v3 that looks like it's intended to create facets. I'll update with my own answer if I can get it working.

Comment: Before posting the answr, I have evaluated the stacked axes, even because I'm using them in my application. Unfortunately they have some limitations for faceting. For instance, you can not add a title or have space between them. Therefore the risk is to have a complex picture to read comparing with a normal faceting. For instance, the picture that you showed here can't be implemented by stacked axes (title as AAPL, Amazon, etc).